# Zendframework2 and Netbeans autosuggestion(intelsense) issue?

Tags: netbeans, zend-framework2

I am trying to create Login application using Zend framework2. For this I am using netbeans. I don't no for some reason intelsense are not shown in netbeans IDE.  I have included zend library in inlcude path.  But for annotation I am not getting autosuggestion, however for other thing it netabeans shows autosuggestion method.  To avoid confusion I have uploaded figure below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Netbeans 7.2 ? Did you download the right version ?

Quoting form the site:

> The first thing which is different is the look of annotations in code
>   completion. As you can see, there is a new annotation icon and an
>   annotation type. Because we have a lot of modules with their own
>   annotations, we differ them in code completion window by their type.
>   We support annotations for:
>
> ApiGen (legacy PHPDoc annotations), PHPUnit, Doctrine 2 (ORM and ODM)
>   and Symfony 2.

[Click here to have a look](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/brand_new_annotations_support)

Comment: DOwnload the APIGEN plugin , at [here](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/34676/php-apigen-api-documentation-generator)